# How to manipulate inside of a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

We have a component `<Book />` looks like following:

```
const Book = () => (<>
  <Title />
  <Thumbnail />
  <Author />
</>)
```

And I want to give it a little change into this component, such looks like:

```
const CustomBook = () => (<>
  <Title />
  <h2>Hi, I am a subtitle</h2>
  <Thumbnail>
  <Author />
</>)
```

Let’s say new version of  `<Book />` is released:

```
const Book = () => (<>
  <Title />
  <Author /> {/* Position is changed *}
  <Thumbnail /> {/* Position is changed *}
</>)
```

The position of `<Author />` and `<Thumbnail` /> is now changed. But the `<CustomBook />` doesn’t follow the structure of the new `<Book />` since I wrote my own structure.
But what I actually wanted to do in the `<CustomBook />` component was just appending an element after the `<Title />` component.

Subsequently, one of my coworkers have suggested me the following approach:

```
<Book>
  {builder => builder
        // Assume that the keys are initially defined inside of the component
    .appendAfter('title', <h2>Foobar</h2>) 
    .appendBefore(...)
    .replace('foo', <Bar />)
    .setProps('foo', { bar: 100 })
  }
</Book>
```

But I don’t think it’s a good approach because:
1. The component is not self-descriptive.
2. The component is against React’s principals, that we should not manipulate the DOM directly. (Although it’s the virtual DOM)

I could define props such like `afterTitle`, but there are many components inside of the `<Book />` component, therefore, it’s going to be hard to define all of the props. And we also should be able to remove or replace the elements.

I’m curious if there is a react-ish way to achieve this goal. 
Thank you in advance.

---

(Edited)

TL;DR

Is there a way to append/replace/remove some component inside of a component, by an internally existing component, no matter how component internally changes, without defining props.

(Edited #2)

I'll publish the `<Book />` component on NPM. So developers can't modify it. I want to allow developers to customize the component's internal DOM tree with such API as `insertAfter('title', <Subtitle />)`. But not by props because I want to make it flexible.

Comment: Its bit confusing what you are asking. 
"no matter how component internally changes" : Who changes the component ? It should be parent component, which will decide what to render based on some props state.
What do you mean by "without defining props" ?

Comment: @Dev Even though I asked the question, I'm confusing either because I don't think it's possible in React. I'll add more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you checked the **[`reconciliation`](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)**

> **1.** *Component instances are updated and reused based on their key.*
>
> **2.** *React uses the key to match children in the original tree with children in the subsequent tree*

Please provide key to each component and siblings elements

```
const CustomBook = () => (<>
  <Title  key={1}/>
  <h2 key={2}>Hi, I am a subtitle</h2>
  <Author key={3}/> 
  <Thumbnail key={4}/>
</>)
```

Note : for example purpose I have used 1,2,3.Please provide as per your requirements.

Comment: If you are using React.Fragments there is no need for `key`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not necessary to have two separate components (one for `<Book>` and another `<CustomBook>`), then you can simply pass props to `Book`, for example, `subtitle`. Then in your `Book` component, you can check if it has a subtitle, and if so, display the subtitle. Ie,

```
const Book = () => (<>
  <Title />
  { this.props.subtitle ? <h2>this.props.subtitle</h2> : null }
  <Thumbnail />
  <Author />
</>)
```

Comment: You could check for `this.props.subtitle` and not need an extra boolean for `hasSubtitle`

e.g `{this.props.subtitle ? <h2>this.props.subtitle</h2> : null}`

Comment: @FrancisLeigh You're right, its better. I updated the answer

Comment: It can be further simplified as { this.props.subtitle &&  <h2>this.props.subtitle</h2> }

Comment: Hmm, I'm actually not asking about it. Probably my question is not straight-forward. I'll update the question.